# How to disable Listener for certain routes in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, listener

We have in our symfony2 application with several Listeners the case that they should do nothing, if the user comes via a certain route.

One option to achieve this is to check the Uri which is quite ugly.

```
protected function inThisCaseIgnore()
{
    return in_array(
        $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getRequestUri(),
        array(self::VERIFICATION_PATH, '/api/1/', self::WEBSERVICE_PATH)
    );
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve this? I am thinking about maybe annotations?
If yes how to do it?

Comment: What event do you listen?

Comment: onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to mark the routes to be ignored in their definitions.  Something like:

```
cerad_game__project__game_report__update:
  pattern:  /project/{_project}/game-report/{_game}/update
  defaults:
    _ignore: true
    _model:      cerad_game__project__game_report__update__model_factory
    _form:       cerad_game__project__game_report__update__form_factory
    _controller: cerad_game__project__game_report__update__controller:action
    _template: '@CeradGame/Project/GameReport/Update/GameReportUpdateTwigPage.html.twig'
```

A simple $request->has('_ignore') will do the trick.

Comment: Would that be the routing.yml ? Or where would that go?

Comment: Wherever you define your routes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: We have our routing information as annotation in our controllers. Do you know what is the proper format  there?

Comment: Perhaps the defaults section might help? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own event listener that has a higher priority than every listener that should optionally be skipped. In this listener you can perform whatever test you need to make to detect if other listeners should be skipped. If that's the case just call the `stopPropagation()` method of the `Event` instance you get passed.

But you need to be careful which priority you use to register your listener as Symfony itself performs a lot of things through event listeners and skipping them might lead to unexpected behaviour. However, you can see the [list of registered core event listeners in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html).

Comment: That does not really tackle my problem. My problem is in the "perform whatever test" . And that would be the same in whichever Listener I would perform it.

Comment: So you literally want to skip listeners based on the name of a route?

Comment: Or based on the controller method.

Comment: You can access the controller and route information through the request's attribute parameter bag (using `$request->attributes->get('_controller')` or `$request->attributes->get('_route')`).